# Why not exported numbers in csv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

please help solve the problem.

i create scaffold Product, fill it, and try export product data to csv-format file.
application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  require 'csv'
end
```

product controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv do
        headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"user-list\""
        headers['Content-Type'] ||= 'text/csv'
      end
    end    
  end
end
```

app/views/users/index.csv.erb:

```
<%- headers = [
  'title', 
  'is_catalog', 
  'parent_id', 
  'lft', 
  'rgt', 
  'description'
] -%>
<%= CSV.generate_line headers %>
<%- @products.each do |product| -%>
  <%= CSV.generate_line([
    product.title, 
    product.is_catalog, 
    product.parent_id, 
    product.lft, 
    product.rgt, 
    product.description
  ]) %>
<%- end -%>
```

schema:

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "description"
  t.boolean  "is_catalog"
  t.integer  "parent_id"
  t.integer  "lft"
  t.integer  "rgt"
end
```

but after open link 'host/products.csv', downloaded csv-file which contain '###' symbols in 'lft' column. see it on screenshot http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=f08a98e485285e4adb23f5c148620aa2

please help export 'lft' column values

Comment: http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/formulatips/qt/numbersign_err.htm

Comment: You should look at the CSV with a text editor and see if the text is correct.

Comment: thanks! i open file with other editor and look normal nubmers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '###' symbols are the Excel representation when a number is too big to display in the available column width. So just widen the colums by dragging the columnheader or double clicking the right separator in the column headers so that the widt is automaticly adjusted to the value with the maximum width.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the result number is too wide for your spreadsheet software (Excel ?). If it is correctly displayed when you open your file with a text editor, you're ok. Your data is well-written.